# Split String (or List of Strings) to individual columns in spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Given a dataframe "df" and a list of columns "colStr", is there a way in Spark Dataframe to extract or reference those columns from the data frame.

Here's an example -

```
val in = sc.parallelize(List(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
val df = in.map(x => (x, x+1, x+2)).toDF("c1", "c2", "c3")
val keyColumn = "c2" // this is either a single column name or a string of column names delimited by ','
val keyGroup = keyColumn.split(",").toSeq.map(x => col(x))

import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import sqlContext.implicits._

val ranker = Window.partitionBy(keyGroup).orderBy($"c2")

val new_df= df.withColumn("rank", rank.over(ranker))

new_df.show()
```

The above errors out with

```
error: overloaded method value partitionBy with alternatives
(cols:org.apache.spark.sql.Column*)org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.WindowSpec <and>
(colName: String,colNames: String*)org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.WindowSpec
cannot be applied to (Seq[org.apache.spark.sql.Column])
```

Appreciate the help. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to group data frame by the columns in the `keyGroup` list, you can pass `keyGroup: _*` as parameter to `partitionBy` function:

```
val ranker = Window.partitionBy(keyGroup: _*).orderBy($"c2")    
val new_df= df.withColumn("rank", rank.over(ranker))

new_df.show
+---+---+---+----+
| c1| c2| c3|rank|
+---+---+---+----+
|  0|  1|  2|   1|
|  5|  6|  7|   1|
|  2|  3|  4|   1|
|  4|  5|  6|   1|
|  3|  4|  5|   1|
|  1|  2|  3|   1|
+---+---+---+----+
```

Comment: wonder why the downvote, looks like the right answer to me too.

Comment: @PascalSoucy I don't know either, especially if the down voter doesn't leave a comment in this case. I will leave it as is since I can't figure out why it's wrong. Thanks for the comment though.